# Is there a way to export/import project variables?

Tags: qgis, qgis-variable

I have a project with around 20 variables (for parameterizing font/line sizes, colors, etc. across multiple layers) in the Project Variables table (i.e. in Project>Settings>Variables/Project). I would like to use many of them in a new project. Is there any way to export these variables and import them into the new project? Or must I create all of them by hand again? I am using 3.28.6-Firenze

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a direct way, but there is a workaround: save/export your project as qgs file (or unzip the default qgz project file) and open it in a text-editor. The variables then can be found under the tag `<Variables>`. Copy and paste them to the other project files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to create a *new* project based on this, why not simply make a copy of your existing project, remove layers and what else you don't need and continue from there?

You could also save it as a project template for easier re-use.